# Sql Query to Linq To Sql

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq-to-sql

I have some difficulties when it comes to multi-table query in Linq to Sql.
I have 3 tables:

- Product
- Row (with *Fk-ProductId*)
- Price (with *Fk-RowId*)

I'd like to retrieve the min(Price) for a product. I was able to get the right Sql query, but now I need to 'translate' this query into Linq To Sql.
Can you please help me ?

Here the Sql query:

```
SELECT Min(cp.Price) 
FROM Products p, Rows r, ConstantPrices cp 
WHERE p.ProductId = r.ProductId AND 
      r.RowId = cp.RowId AND 
      p.ProductId = XXX;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution:

```
decimal? min = (from p in db.Products
               join r in db.Rows on p.ProductId equals r.ProductId
               join cp in db.ConstantPrices on r.RowId equals cp.RowId
               where p.ProductId == 1
               select cp.Price).Min();
```

Comment: Don't forget to make the field nullable, as I mentioned in my answer not doing so would throw an exception if there are no items.

Answer (score 0):

```
var productQuery = from p in myContext
               where p.id == someId
               select (double?) p.Row.Price;
var minPrice = productQuery.Min();
```

Its important the nullable in there, otherwise it would fail if there are no products or rows or prices in the system.

**Its not about translating** queries, its about taking advantage of what linq2sql gives you.